# How do you update the value you delegated from one class to the other?

Tags: swift, protocols, delegation, data-sharing

I'm having an issue with Delegating. I'm relatively new to the concept, and but conceptually I get it and it's importance. I'm just having trouble using it. I can't seem to pass data from one class to the other. I know there are existing examples of delegation out there on stack overflow but they aren't quite capturing my misunderstanding. I get the use of protocols, delegation, and calling it in a class. I believe there just some small nuance that I'm missing... And it's visible in the lack of functionality in my code

```
//my protocol:

protocol StingHolder {
    func StringPasser(ThisText text: String)
}
```

Creating the delegate protocol relation, places data to be passed then dismisses the View Controller

```
// my classes for placing data to be passed

class changeLabel: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate{

   var Delegate: StingHolder?


    @IBOutlet weak var TexrBeingPassed: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        TexrBeingPassed.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }



    @IBAction func ButtonPassingDataOtherView(_ sender: Any) {

            Delegate?.StringPasser(ThisText: TexrBeingPassed.text!)
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)


    }
}
```

Creates an instance of the change lable class and its delegate and sets itself to be the delegate *supposedly changes the label, but It doesn't

```
///class to receive data


class ViewController: UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var LableName: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var lableChange = changeLabel()
        lableChange.Delegate = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBAction func EditController(_ sender: Any) {

        var storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Test", bundle: nil)
        var ViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TestView")
        self.present(ViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


}
```

inherits the protocol and tells it to change the label to whatever the changelabel class delegate has passes

```
// extension view controller inheriting the protocol

extension ViewController : StingHolder{

    func StringPasser(ThisText text: String){

        print("Delegate is working")
        LableName.text = text
        ///
    }  
}
```

I want the one view controller to edit the text label of another view controller

Comment: Is the VC in the storyboard with the ID `TestView` of type `changeView`?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't give the same name, I apologize for any confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object which you have `self` as a delegate of, is not the same object presented on the screen.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // "labelChange.delegate" is set...
    var lableChange = changeLabel()
    lableChange.Delegate = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


@IBAction func EditController(_ sender: Any) {

    var storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Test", bundle: nil)
    // but "ViewController" is presented
    var ViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TestView")
    self.present(ViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

`labelChange` and `ViewController` are two different, independent objects. One created by calling `init` directly, and the other created by calling `storyBoard.instantiateViewController`. You should set the delegate of the *latter* instead:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // "labelChange.delegate" can be deleted
}


@IBAction func EditController(_ sender: Any) {

    var storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Test", bundle: nil)
    if let ViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TestView") as? labelChange {
        ViewController.delegate = self
        self.present(ViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: So what this change is doing is, making the ViewController into the changeLableView controller then presenting itself as that view controller?... Is there not a way to pass data without making a view controller just a different view controller?

Comment: @rabusmccaleb I’m not really changing something to something else. I’m just setting the delegate of the correct object - the VC that is presented, not some random object that was created in viewDidLoad and done nothing with.